# Settings schema 'com.github.Suzie97.epoch' is not installed

Tags: settings, glib, meson-build

This is the gschema.xml code for my app:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schemalist>
    <schema path="/com/github/Suzie97/epoch"
    id="com.github.Suzie97.epoch"
    gettext-domain - "com.github.Suzie97.epoch">
        <key name="pos-x" type="i">
            <default>360</default>
            <summary>Most recent x position of Epoch</summary>
            <description>Most recent x position of Epoch</description>
        </key>
        
        <key name="pos-y" type="i">
            <default>360</default>
            <summary>Most recent y position of Epoch</summary>
            <description>Most recent y position of Epoch</description>
        </key>
    </schema>
</schemalist>
```

This is the meson.build file to install the gschema:

```
install_data(
    'gschema.xml',
    install_dir: join_paths (get_option ('datadir'), 'glib-2.0', 'schemas'),
    rename: meson.project_name() + '.gschema.xml'
)
```

When I compile this error is displayed:
`Settings schema 'com.github.Suzie97.epoch' is not installed`

This is the post_install.py script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess

install_prefix = os.environ['MESON_INSTALL_PREFIX']
schemadir = os.path.join(install_prefix, 'share/glib-2.0/schemas')
    
if not os.environ.get('DESTDIR'):
    print('Compiling the gsettings schemas ... ')
    subprocess.call(['glib-compile-schemas', schemadir])
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

There are various issues at play:

1. the name of the schema file should match your application's identifier—in this case, it would be `com.github.Suzie97.epoch.gschema.xml`
2. you should not rename the file on installation; just installing it under the `glib-2.0/schemas` data directory is enough
3. you should call `glib-compile-schemas $datadir/glib-2.0/schemas` to "compile" all the schemas once you installed your application; this is typically done as a post-installation script in Meson, using [`meson.add_install_script()`](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#meson-object).

GSettings does not use the XML *per se*: the `glib-compile-schemas` tool will generate a cache file that will be shared by all applications using GSettings, and will be fast to load. This is why GSettings will warn you that the schema is not installed: you are missing that last compilation step.

Comment: Hey, I am new to programming, and I don't clearly understand the points you have mentioned. I tried renaming the file as you have said in point 1, but that didn't work. When I remove the line that renames the file on installation, the build stops working. And as for the third point, I have a written a post_install.py script, but it is still not working.